# Unsubscribe users when using transactional email template in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using the [Sendgrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/) and I want users to be able to unsubscribe when I send them emails using transactional email templates with Sendgrid.

When adding the "Unsubscribe" module in my template, then it looks all empty and without the unsubscribe link when I send it:

[image]

Is it possible to make the template display the right unsubscribe link?

Note I do not want to use the "Settings > Tracking > Subscription Tracking" option as that can't be added in the template and looks quite bad outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll still want to use "Subscription Tracking" in the Settings section of SendGrid. The difference is you'll use the Replacement Tag:
[image: Subscription Settings - "Replacement Tag"]

I've set it to `%unsub_url%` and can use it in an email like:

```html
<a href="%unsub_url%"/>Unsubscribe</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Man! You're awesome